# Boolean Expression Simplification XOR

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I have been trying to express XOR in terms of just the '&' and '~' operators. I have managed to get the original XOR definition

(~x & y) | (x & ~y)

down to ~(x & y) & ~(~x & ~y) using DeMorgan's Law.

Using Wolfram I have found that this expression can be simplified down to ~x & y. Could someone show me the steps involved to do this as I just can't work it out.

Comment: When $x$ is true and $y$ is false, the XOR is true, but this doesn't satisfy Wolfram alpha's expression.  You may want to check the derivation again.

Comment: That is very strange. I see the logic and have drawn up the truth table for it but if I have the function int bitXor(int x, int y), if I have:

1) return ~(~x & ~y) & ~(x & y)        OR
2) return ~x&y

I always return the same result. Is ~(~x & ~y) & ~(x & y) the simplest form?

Comment: Your DeMorgan's is wrong.  (~x & y) | (x & ~y) = ~(~x & y) & ~(x & ~y) = (x  | ~y) & (~x |  y).  Apply DeMorgan's to both terms.

Answer (score 1):

$$ x ⊕ y = \bar xy + x \bar y$$
Take DeMorgan's.  Take inverse, invert terms and change operator.
$$ x ⊕ y = \overline {\bar xy} • \overline {x \bar y}$$
So this is as good as it gets for AND and NOT operators.  2 NANDs, 1 AND and 2 NOTs.  NAND = AND + NOT

[image: XOR with AND and NOTs]